# How do I set the permissions and timestamps of one directory to match anothers?

Tags: ruby, filesystems, stat

Given directory `./a` and `./b` how do I use ruby to set the permissions and timestamps of `./b` to be the same as `./a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `touch` command (at least on Linux) has a `-r` option:

```
   -r, --reference=FILE
          use this file’s times instead of current time
```

You can call `touch` from your Ruby program to do what you want. The `chmod` command has a similar flag.